# Haskell - loop over user input

Tags: haskell, io

I have a program in haskell that has to read arbitrary lines of input from the user and when the user is finished the accumulated input has to be sent to a function.

In an imperative programming language this would look like this:

```
content = ''
while True:
    line = readLine()
    if line == 'q':
        break
    content += line
func(content)
```

I find this incredibly difficult to do in haskell so I would like to know if there's an haskell equivalent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's reasonably simple in Haskell. The trickiest part is that you want to accumulate the sequence of user inputs. In an imperative language you use a loop to do this, whereas in Haskell the canonical way is to use a recursive helper function. It would look something like this:

```
getUserLines :: IO String                      -- optional type signature
getUserLines = go ""
  where go contents = do
    line <- getLine
    if line == "q"
        then return contents
        else go (contents ++ line ++ "\n")     -- add a newline
```

This is actually a definition of an IO action which returns a `String`. Since it is an IO action, you access the returned string using the `<-` syntax rather than the `=` assignment syntax. If you want a quick overview, I recommend reading [The IO Monad For People Who Simply Don't Care](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/11/io-monad-for-people-who-simply-dont.html).

You can use this function at the GHCI prompt like this

```
>>> str <- getUserLines
Hello<Enter>     -- user input
World<Enter>     -- user input
q<Enter>         -- user input
>>> putStrLn str
Hello            -- program output
World            -- program output
```

Comment: Now, would you really write this in Haskell?  Appending `line` to `contents` everytime gives you poor performance.  The `contents` that you want in the end is a prefix of what a single call to `getContents` will give you.

Comment: That's a fair point - but I thought it was worth explaining how to do this "from the ground up", to get a feel for working in the IO monad (which is probably the most confusing part of Haskell for newcomers). It also has the benefit of separating the user input from the processing to be done in the input, which your answer does not. I'll add an appendix about `getContents.`

Comment: OK, point taken, I'm taking back my initial -1.  But, educational purposes left aside, I'd consider code like this bad Haskell.  For people who care, at least...  :-)

Answer (score 21):

The Haskell equivalent to iteration is recursion.  You would also need to work in the `IO` monad, if you have to read lines of input.  The general picture is:

```
import Control.Monad

main = do
  line <- getLine
  unless (line == "q") $ do
    -- process line
    main
```

If you just want to accumulate all read lines in `content`, you don't have to do that.  Just use `getContents` which will retrieve (lazily) all user input.  Just stop when you see the `'q'`.  In quite idiomatic Haskell, all reading could be done in a single line of code:

```
main = mapM_ process . takeWhile (/= "q") . lines =<< getContents
  where process line = do -- whatever you like, e.g.
                          putStrLn line
```

If you read the first line of code **from right to left**, it says:

1. get everything that the user will provide as input (never fear, this is lazy);
2. split it in lines as it comes;
3. only take lines as long as they're not equal to "q", stop when you see such a line;
4. and call `process` for each line.

If you didn't figure it out already, you need to read carefully a Haskell tutorial!

Comment: i'd use getLine instead of readLn to get executable version, and also add `import Control.Monad`

Comment: @jev, agreed.  I used `readLn` to make it more general, but it may be confusing for someone who just wants to read lines.

Answer (score 2):

Using `pipes-4.0`, which is coming out this weekend:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

f :: [String] -> IO ()
f = ??

main = do
    contents <- P.toListM (P.stdinLn >-> P.takeWhile (/= "q"))
    f contents
```

That loads all the lines into memory.  However, you can also process each line as it is being generated, too:

```
f :: String -> IO ()

main = runEffect $
    for (P.stdinLn >-> P.takeWhile (/= "q")) $ \str -> do
        lift (f str)
```

That will stream the input and never load more than one line into memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

input <- unlines . takeWhile (/= "q") . lines <$> getContents
```

Then input would be what the user wrote up until (but not including) the q.