# Haskell: looping over user input gracefully

Tags: loops, haskell, monads

This is an example from `Learn You a Haskell`:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "hello, what's your name?"
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn ("Hey, " ++ name ++ ", you rock!")
```

The same redone without `do` for clarity:

```
main =
    putStrLn "hello, what's your name?" >>
    getLine >>= \name ->
    putStrLn $ "Hey, " ++ name ++ ", you rock!"
```

How am I supposed to loop it cleanly (until "q"), the Haskell way (use of `do` discouraged)?

I borrowed this from [Haskell - loop over user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573924/haskell-loop-over-user-input)

```
main = mapM_ process . takeWhile (/= "q") . lines =<< getLine
    where process line = do
                            putStrLn line
```

for starters, but it won't loop.

Comment: The use of `do` isn't discouraged. There's some discussion about whether or not to use `do` notation when introducing monads to beginners because it might give them even crazier ideas about what monads are, but in normal haskell use of do is fine. Also, if you know how to do it with `do`, you know  how to do it without. Your problem here has nothing to do with `do` notation.

Comment: Also, your last code segment you have there doesn't work because you wrote `getLine` instead of `getContents`

Comment: [Here's](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html) a library which defines a large number of looping combinators.

Comment: 2 *Cubic*: discouraged for me only :) . To stay away from crazy ideas precisely.

Comment: 2 *Cubic*: `getContents` helps. Unfortunately, I'm still at a loss about how to insert prompt/response into the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call main again and check if your string is "q" or not.

```
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main =
    putStrLn "hello, what's your name?" >>
    getLine >>= \name ->
                  when (name /= "q") $ (putStrLn $ "Hey, " ++ name ++ ", you rock!") >> main

λ> main
hello, what's your name?
Mukesh Tiwari
Hey, Mukesh Tiwari, you rock!
hello, what's your name?
Alexey Orlov
Hey, Alexey Orlov, you rock!
hello, what's your name?
q
λ>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the exact answer. Is there a way to employ `if` instead of `when`, BTW?

Comment: About `if`: not here, I see. `when` exists precisely for this kind of job.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov No, `if` works perfectly fine. `IO` actions are just values you can shuffle around: `main = _ >>= \name -> if name /= "q" then main else return ()`. That's how `when` is implemented: `when cond act = if cond then act else pure ()` (`pure` = `return` for `IO` (and `Monad`s in general)).

Comment: Thanks! It makes one think... Why the trouble of defining `when` if is does not make your life any easier :) ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can also use laziness on IO type by adapting the [`System.IO.Lazy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyio-0.1.0.4/docs/System-IO-Lazy.html) package. It basically includes only `run :: T a -> IO a` and `interleave :: IO a -> T a` functions to convert IO actions into lazy ones back and forth.

```
import qualified System.IO.Lazy as LIO

getLineUntil :: String -> IO [String]
getLineUntil s = LIO.run ((sequence . repeat $ LIO.interleave getLine) >>= return . takeWhile (/=s))

printData :: IO [String] -> IO ()
printData d = d >>= print . sum . map (read :: String -> Int)

*Main> printData $ getLineUntil "q"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
q
45
```

In the above code we construct an infinite list of lazy `getLine`s by `repeat $ LIO.interleave getLine` of type `[T String]` and by `sequence` we turn it into `T [String]` type and proceed reading up until "q" is received. The `printData` utility function is summing up and printing the entered integers.